# How can I get Spring-Security to return a 401 response as a JSON format?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a ReST API to an application with all controllers found under `/api/`, these all return JSON responses with a `@ControllerAdvice` which handles all exceptions to map to JSON formatted results.

This works great as of spring 4.0 `@ControllerAdvice` now supports matching on annotations. What I can't work out is how to return a JSON result for a 401 - Unauthenticated and 400 - Bad Request responses.

Instead Spring is simply returning the response to the container (tomcat) which renders this as HTML. How can I intercept this and render a JSON result using the same technique that my `@ControllerAdvice` is using.

**security.xml**

```xml
<bean id="xBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="com.example.security.XBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="realmName" value="com.example.unite"/>
</bean>
<security:http pattern="/api/**"
               create-session="never"
               use-expressions="true">
  <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="xBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
  <security:session-management />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</security:http>
```

**XBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
public class XBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                               authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I can solve 401 by using the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` to write directly to the output stream, but I'm not sure it's the best approach.

```
public class XBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final ObjectMapper om;

    @Autowired
    public XBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint(ObjectMapper om) {
        this.om = om;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        om.writeValue(httpResponse.getOutputStream(),
                      new ApiError(request.getRequestURI(),
                      HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                      "You must sign in or provide basic authentication."));
    }

}
```

I am yet to figure out how to handle 400 though, I once tried a catch all controller which did work, but it seemed that sometimes it would have odd conflicting behaviour with other controllers that I don't want to revisit.

My `ControllerAdvice` implementation has a catch all which if spring throws any exception for bad request (400) it should in theory capture it, but it does not:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = {RestController.class})
public class ApiControllerAdvisor {
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> exception(Throwable exception,
                                              WebRequest request,
                                              HttpServletRequest req) {
        ApiError err = new ApiError(req.getRequestURI(), exception);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(err, err.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: For a 401 your solution seems appropriate: If it's an unauthenticated request it will never hit your controller, so the advice is no help. For the 400 i think it depends. If it's returned because no matching signature in a controller has been found i'm quite unsure if the advice kicks in (obviously it doesn't).

Comment: Thanks Dirk, just wasn't completely sure about the `400`, it does work well though. For the `400` I have tested where a mapping expects a request parameter, if I omit the parameter I get the ordinary `HTML` response. It does actually make sense thinking about it because the controller method will not be called, it's prior this that spring is finding a fault so again the advisor would not be called similarly as with the 401.

Answer (score 17):

I actually found myself asking the very same question a few weeks ago - As Dirk pointed out in the comments, @ControllerAdvice will only kick in if an exception is thrown from within a controller method, so will inevitably not catch all things (I was actually trying to solve the  case for a JSON response for a 404 error).

The solution I settled on, although not entirely pleasant (hopefully if you get a better answer I will change my approach) is handling the error mapping in the Web.xml - I added the following, which will override the tomcat default error pages with specific URL mappings:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/resourcenotfound</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/errors/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, if any page returns a 404, it is handled by my error controller something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/errors")
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @RequestMapping("resourcenotfound")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonResponse resourceNotFound(HttpServletRequest request, Device device) throws Exception {
        return new JsonResponse("ERROR", 404, "Resource Not Found");
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @RequestMapping("unauthorised")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonResponse unAuthorised(HttpServletRequest request, Device device) throws Exception {
        return new JsonResponse("ERROR", 401, "Unauthorised Request");
    }
}
```

It all still feels pretty grim - and of course is a global handling of errors - so if you didn't always want a 404 response to be json (if you were serving a normal webapp of the same application) then it doesnt work so well. But like I said, its what I settled on to get moving, here's hoping there is a nicer way!

Comment: I was thinking of doing this too, I've just been experimenting with creating a new implementation of [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.html). It took me the evening to solve this, but I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Having implemented my approach, I'm not sure which I prefer actually. I'm just going to wait a little and see how I feel before accepting :)

Comment: I forgot about this question until it just got bumped. I've just read what I was on about and in the end I still prefer my solution, though many have voted yours so I still feel conflicted and would prefer to accept someone else's answer other than my own. The reason I am more fond of my approach is it handles cases without controller mappings. It is possible that someone could just access `/unauthorised` on your site and get the error, I believe this should not be exposed.

Comment: @BrettRyan no probs, I won't take offence if you select your own answer :)  (and you are right, you would need to protect elsewhere to stop exposing the error endpoints directly)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to handle this if I'm not using a config file (I'm just using Spring annotations and doing everything programatically)

Comment: @Kylar You just using plain Spring-MVC? or Spring Boot? I'm not sure if its possible in the code equivalent of web.xml, however, if you look at how Spring-Boot gets around the problem (when you are hosting on traditional app server), they have just implemented a standard Filter to wrap around the request/response that basically intercepts the response and checks for issues and re-directs it.

Comment: @Kylar  You can see the Spring-Boot ErrorPageFilter here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/support/ErrorPageFilter.java and I wrote a little about it (in Spring Boot context here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/spring-boot-tomcat-error-handling.html

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by implementing my own version of [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) and subclassing [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.html). It took a bit to work this out and you must override most methods, though the following has done exactly what I'm after.

Firstly the basics are to create an implementation.

```
public class CustomHandlerExceptionResolver extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
    private final ObjectMapper om;
    @Autowired
    public CustomHandlerExceptionResolver(ObjectMapper om) {
        this.om = om;
        setOrder(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldApplyTo(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
        return request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api");
    }
}
```

And now register it in your servlet context.

This now does nothing different, but will be the first [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) to be tried and will match any request starting with a context path of `/api` (note: you could make this a configurable parameter).

Next, we now can override any method that spring encounters errors on, there are 15 on my count.

What I have found is that I can write to the response directly and return an empty [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html) object or return null if my method did not eventually handle the fault which causes the next exception resolver to be tried.

As an example to handle situations where a request binding fault occurred I have done the following:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView handleServletRequestBindingException(ServletRequestBindingException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
    ApiError ae = new ApiError(request.getRequestURI(), ex, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    response.setStatus(ae.getStatusCode());
    om.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), ae);
    return new ModelAndView();
}
```

The only disadvantage here is that because I'm writing to the stream myself I'm not using any message converters to handle writing the response, so if I wanted to support XML and JSON API's at the same time it would not be possible, fortunately I'm only interested in supporting JSON, but this same technique could be enhanced to use view resolvers to determine what to render in etc.

If anyone has a better approach I'd still be interested in knowing how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

You should look out to set error code in ResponseEntity, as below:

```
new ResponseEntity<String>(err, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Comment: Where are you suggesting this should be done? I am setting this in my entry point which is returned correctly. When writing to the stream directly this does also work correctly though I was not sure if it was the most appropriate way or if a better way exists.

Answer (score -3):

Simply catch the exception in your controller and return response you want to send.

```
   try {
    // Must be called from request filtered by Spring Security, otherwise SecurityContextHolder is not updated
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);
    logger.debug("Logging in with [{}]", authentication.getPrincipal());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
} catch (Exception e) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    logger.error("Failure in autoLogin", e);
}
```