# Handle 401 Error (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I can handle 404 error.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public void noHandlerFoundException (HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
       //some code
    }
```

But how to handle 401 error?

**Edit** I am using Java and not web.xml

**Edit** What should I put in NoHandlerFoundException to handle the HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED

**Edit**

I have method unsuccessfulAuthentication, when authentication failed:

```
public class StatelessLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter { 

    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                      AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Authentication request failed: " + failed.toString());
                    logger.debug("Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication");
                    logger.debug("Delegating to authentication failure handler " + failureHandler);
                }

        //        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //        response.getWriter().write(jsonService.toString(jsonService.getResponse(false, "Не удалось авторизоваться", "401")));

                rememberMeServices.loginFail(request, response);
                failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);

            }
        }
```

This code sent 401 error html. I need to send json, you can see it in comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Spring-Security to return a 401 response as a JSON format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783583/how-can-i-get-spring-security-to-return-a-401-response-as-a-json-format)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete handler for all a little collection of error pages :

```
@Controller
public class ErrorCodeController extends BaseController {

    @ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
    @RequestMapping(value="errorPage400", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleBadRequest(ApplicationException ex,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) { 
        map.addAttribute("http-error-code", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return processErrorCodes(ex,response,map);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
    @RequestMapping(value="errorPage401", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,reason="Unauthorized Request")
    public String handleUnauthorizedRequest(ApplicationException ex,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) { 
        map.addAttribute("http-error-code", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return processErrorCodes(ex,response,map);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
    @RequestMapping(value="errorPage404", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleNotFoundRequest(ApplicationException ex,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) { 
        map.addAttribute("http-error-code", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return processErrorCodes(ex,response,map);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
    @RequestMapping(value="errorPage500", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,reason="Internal Server Error")
    public String handleInternalServerError(ApplicationException ex,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) { 
        map.addAttribute("http-error-code", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return processErrorCodes(ex,response,map);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
    public void handleApplicationExceptions(Throwable exception, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }

    private String processErrorCodes(ApplicationException ex,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map){
        map.addAttribute("class", ClassUtils.getShortName(ex.getClass()));
        map.addAttribute("message", ex.getMessage());
        map.addAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getErrorMessage());
        map.addAttribute("errorCode", ex.getErrorCode());
        map.addAttribute("timestamp", ex.getCurrentDate());
        return "errorPage";
    }


}
```

Base Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseController {

    // Remember to add any exception that you suspect can be thrown in this web application.


@ExceptionHandler({ApplicationException.class,NullPointerException.class})
    public ModelAndView handleException(Throwable exception,HttpServletRequest req) {

        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        ApplicationException ex = new ApplicationException();
        String timeStamp = ex.getCurrentDate().toString();
        //String temp = ClassUtils.getShortName(ex.getClass());
        //model.addAttribute("class", ClassUtils.getShortName(ex.getClass()));
        model.addAttribute("timeStamp", timeStamp);
        return new ModelAndView("errorPage", model);
    }
```

Web.xml :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>myApp</display-name>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage400.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage401.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/errorPage.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

Comment: i'm using java Config, not web.xml And I need to send json, not redirecting to error page

Comment: and we are supposed to know this from .. ? Format your post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but i struggeled as well, so here is my solution that works well for Tomcat only.

Invoke the following method in your `*DispatcherServletInitializer`/`WebAppInitializer`'s `#onStartup(...)` method.

```
Field appContextInFacade = ApplicationContextFacade.class.getDeclaredField("context");
appContextInFacade.setAccessible(true);
ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext) appContextInFacade.get(servletContext);
Field appContextInContext = ApplicationContext.class.getDeclaredField("context");
appContextInContext.setAccessible(true);
StandardContext context = (StandardContext) appContextInContext.get(appContext);
ErrorPage defaultErrorPage = new ErrorPage();
defaultErrorPage.setLocation("/myinternalerrorhandlercontroller");
context.addErrorPage(defaultErrorPage); // You may have to use reflection here as well.
```

Then add a controller that is capable of handling those error requests:

```
@RequestMapping("/myinternalerrorhandlercontroller")
public ResponseEntity<T> renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
```

You can extract the error details using:

```
(Integer) httpRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
```

**Important notice:**

- You have to handle all `RequestMethod`s.
- You have to handle all `Content-Type`s (=> Return bytes or register a fallback HttpMessageConverter that can convert your error object to json regardless of what was requested).
- Your error page must never throw exceptions or fail to return a response.
- The error page is only shown if the usual `@ExceptionHandler` or similar mechanisms are not invoked or (fail to execute).
- Don't access your applications state such as user auth, because you are outside of their scope and they might not be available or contain invalid data.