# How to catch 401,403 errors and respond as success 200

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web, oauth

I am working in java spring project and using restful web services.For security reasons I have added oAuth spring security.In that when access token is expired,It shows ***401*** *gateway error*.I need to catch those error and respond as ***200*** Http Success status with json error response.For example **`{"error" : "Unauthorized"}`**.What to configure to catch 401 error.Please help me out.

Comment: this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585635/handle-401-error-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

You should use [security-filter-chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). Create filter to have your custom implementation and add it. Below is the example from the documentation.

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
  <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
     <sec:filter-chain pattern="/webServices/**" filters="
           securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCFalse,
           basicAuthenticationFilter,
           exceptionTranslationFilter,
           filterSecurityInterceptor" />
     <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
           securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue,
           formLoginFilter,
           exceptionTranslationFilter,
           filterSecurityInterceptor" />
  </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```